# Getting guard to work with VM, Vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, guard

I saw some of the other answers about this but I need more of a step by step guide.

My host machine is windows 8 and Im running ubuntu/trusty64 server box on vagrant.

The only setting I have on vagrant file is `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000`

I open a terminal on my host machine and `cd` to the shared folder on my host machine then type `listen -f "10.0.0.2:4000"` and its asking my to install celluloid-io.  Do I just type `gem install celluloid-io`?  I've tried this and then it seems to run but says something about a `wdm` adapter since I'm on windows.  Is there a way around this?

On guest machine I type `guard -o "10.0.0.2:4000"` and it asks for celluloid.  I type `gem install celluloid-io` and then it keeps asking for celluloid.

Should I just forget all this and use polling?  Seems easier but not ideal.  How can I get this to work.  I feel like I'm very wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues.  My solution was to change the way Vagrant does the folder sync to "rsync" as described [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/website/docs/source/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html.md).

My host is MacOS, so rsync is built in.  But for windows, you could use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) to install rsync.

Once you've set up folder syncing this way, you can just use Guard as-is, without having to install the listen gem or try to use TCP port forwarding to pass filesystem events from your host to vagrant.